# Django form ValidationError

Tags: python, django, forms, formset

I have two forms in a view. One htlm form includes form and formset, other html form includes just single form.

When I am trying to submit singe form (Reminder), I am getting this error:

```
[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

View:

```
    form_class = CreateEventForm
    second_form_class = modelformset_factory(EventTime, form = EventTimeForm, extra=3, formset=EventTimeFormset)
    third_form_class = Reminder
    model = Event
    template_name = 'eventAdmin.html'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(EventAdminPage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.POST or None, prefix="form", instance = self.object)
            context['formset'] = self.second_form_class(
                self.request.POST or None,
                prefix="formset", 
                queryset=context['event_times'])
            context['reminder_form'] = Reminder(self.request.POST or None)
            return context

        def post(self, request, **kwargs):
            self.object = self.get_object()
            event_times = EventTime.objects.filter(event = self.object).exclude(start_time = None)
            if 'update_event_form' in request.POST:
                form_class = self.get_form_class()
                form = self.form_class(request.POST, prefix="form", instance=self.get_object())
                formset = self.second_form_class(request.POST, prefix="formset", queryset=event_times)
                if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
                    event = form.save()
                    event_times = formset.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/event-admin-%s' %self.kwargs['event_id']) 
                else:
                    return self.render_to_response(
                        self.get_context_data(form=form, formset=formset))
            if 'reminder_form' in request.POST:
                form_class = self.second_form_class
                form_name = 'Reminder'
                form = form_class(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    form.save(commit=False)
                    message = form.cleaned_data.get('text')
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/event-admin-%s' %self.kwargs['event_id']) 
                else:
                    return self.render_to_response(
                        self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

HTML of form that raises error:

```
<form method='POST' action=''><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='3uQyEn4m8bHpM7Jy6a8WKQz5A8Uf6RZF' />


<div id="div_id_text" class="form-group"> <label for="id_text" class="control-label  requiredField">
                Text<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls "> <textarea class="textarea form-control" cols="40" id="id_text" maxlength="500" name="text" rows="10">
</textarea> </div> </div>

            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="reminder_form" value="Send" />
        </form>
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform

Comment: First, make sure you are including the management form in your template. Secondly, it looks like you have forgotten to use the prefix in the `if 'reminder_form' in request.POST:` block where you do `form = form_class(request.POST)`.

Comment: I added prefix in both places (context method when creating instance and in post method), also I added {{ reminder.management_form }}. Still facing the same error

Comment: Posting your html might provide more light.

Comment: added html of form that raises error

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line `{{ form.management_form }}` after the `<form method='POST' action=''>`. This is used by Django to manage the forms within the formset.

```html
<form method='POST' action=''>
  {{ form.management_form }}
  <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='3uQyEn4m8bHpM7Jy6a8WKQz5A8Uf6RZF' />
  <div id="div_id_text" class="form-group"> 
    <label for="id_text" class="control-label  requiredField">
        Text
        <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
    </label> <div class="controls ">
    <textarea class="textarea form-control" cols="40" id="id_text" maxlength="500" name="text" rows="10">

    </textarea> 
    </div> 
  </div>

  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="reminder_form" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Comment: Tried this at least 5 times, the problem is with singe form, not formset, When i submit formset everything is okay, but when form I am facing that error

Comment: try to access `form.errors` to check what is the error and maybe try also to process the formset and the form separately even within the context to try try locate exactly the error.

Comment: form.errors is empty. If I am submitting valid form it is okay, but when form is empty then I am getting that error

Comment: it depends on whether you want to ignore the empty form and save all the other or you want to raise validation error and don't save any data